# Parse Error with npm workspaces

Tags: solidity, solc

I am getting a false error with the solc language server (running on neovim with nvim-lsp). I often use npm workspaces and the language server fails to understand that the dependencies are two directories above. Any idea how to fix it? I am sure the contract has no errors because it compiles without any.

```bash
Diagnostics:
1. ParserError: Source "hardhat/console.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "$PROJECT_ROOT/apps/backend", "$PROJECT_ROOT/apps/backend/node_modules".
```

and the tree is

```
$PROJECT_ROOT
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── node_modules/
├── apps/
│   ├── backend/
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── hardhat.config.js
│   │   ├── tests/
│   │   ├── contracts/
│   │   ├── scripts/
│   │   │   ├── Lock.sol/
```

**NOTE:** anyone looking for a temporary fix, softlink node_modules in workspace directory